# python3 security question, os.system('wget...') vs urllib.request.urlopen(...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, urllib, os.system

Today I faced a strange behavior in a headless driven print server (RaspPi / python3).

I need to download both, either PDFs or rendered python scripts, from a web server.
Until now I did use:

```
src = "https://ssl.server.tld/path/to/file.pdf"
target = "/path/to/saved.pdf"

os.system("wget -O "+target+" "+src)
```

From now on I use:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(src) as response, open(target, 'wb') as out_file:
    data = response.read()
    out_file.write(data)
```

Here's the question:
Since a couple of days obviously the SSL certificate is outdated.
The `os.system()` version throws a NON-PYTHON ERROR

```
https://ssl.***.de/config_page.py
Auflösen des Hostnamen »ssl.***.de (ssl.***s.de)«... 176.***.***.10
Verbindungsaufbau zu ssl.***.de (ssl.***.de)|176.***.***.10|:443... verbunden.
FEHLER: Dem Zertifikat von »ssl.***.de« wird nicht vertraut.
FEHLER: Das Zertifikat von »ssl.***.de« ist abgelaufen.
```

As I mentioned, there is no python error or exception, the file I want is being downloaded, but with a size of 0 bytes. Only the debugger shows the text quoted above in the console output.

The `urllib` version runs as desired, without errors, without console output, and with the correct file.

What am I missing ? Is this a special security behavior of `os.system()` ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: As an aside, you really should use `shlex.quote()` when forming a command line like that; otherwise it'd be possible to inject additional commands there by manipulating `target` and `src`.

Comment: @AKX : Thanx, will go into it. Guess this is more important for the command line sent to os.system(...), isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can tell, `wget` is verifying the certificate while `urlopen` isn't.

If you want `wget` to skip checking the certificate, add the argument `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: The important part for me is to get to know: is this a known behavior of wget and urlopen ? Whereever I can, I will replace os.system() calls with python, so now no need to skip the cert check :)

Comment: The documentation for urllib.request indicates that it doesn't verify the certificate unless you specify the `cafile` or `capath` argument.  The behavior of `wget` is probably more correct.  But you need to give urlopen additional information for it to do certificate checking.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: On a related note, you can use the `certifi` package to get an up-to-date certificate bundle.

Comment: Franks comment "The documentation for..." is worth to be the accepted answer. Thanks so far.